# Unable to hit servlet using JQuery AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, servlets

I am unable to hit my servlet through JavaScript using JQUERY AJAX like below. Please help me our if I miss anything.
NOTE: My application works only on IE

```
function loadB2BServlet() {

            var awdUserId       = g_PQContactTree.selectSingleNode( "//userID" ).text;
            var awdPassword     = g_PQContactTree.selectSingleNode( "//password" ).text;
            alert("UserId " + awdUserId);
            var lookupUrl = "http://localhost:8080/pqawdTestWebApp/AWDB2BAuthentication?awdUserId="+awdUserId ;
            alert("URL " +lookupUrl);
            var xhr = $.ajax({url:lookupUrl,async:false,type:"GET"});
            var xmlDoc = xhr.responseXML;
            alert("Doc " +xmlDoc);
            }
```

My Servlet

```
 <servlet-mapping>  
         <servlet-name>AWDB2BAuthentication</servlet-name>  
         <url-pattern>/AWDB2BAuthentication/*</url-pattern>  
     </servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: Look at your browser's developer tools. Reload the page. What does the JavaScript console say? Can you see your Ajax request in the Net tab? Is it formatted correctly? Does it get a response? Is the response correct?

Comment: In Developer Tools 
Value of xhr {...} Object
When I expand xhr 
statusText "No Transport" String

And response is xmlDoc undefined Undefined
My observation is it is not hitting my servlet

Answer (score 0):

We Can solve this by keeping **$.support.cors = true;** above JQuery Ajax call